# Assets: Wrong Thumbnail After DB Migration

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I dumped my production DB and imported it into my DEV environment, but Assets is showing the wrong thumbnails for S3 images. The full images are correct (they display correctly in the templates), it's just the thumbs that are wrong.

I updated the indexes for those Assets sources, but it didn't fix the problem. I also deleted everything in the `/cache/assets` directory, but nope.

- EE 2.7.2
- Assets 2.2.2

Comment: Here's a trick question - after clearing /cache/assets directory, did you also clear browser's cache?

Comment: ...I *may* have forgotten to do that. (it's fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete all of the files inside `system/expressionengine/cache/assets/`
2. Clear your browser cache.

Voilà.